# Frustrated with FizzBuzz program not returning intended results, first programming assesment

Tags: c#, fizzbuzz

I don't understand where I am going wrong despite sectioning off the code into i.e. 'buzz' and 'fizz' parts, it still adds an increment of one for each number.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Open file
        //=========
        string path = "FizzBuzzText.txt";
        FileInfo txtFile = new FileInfo(path);

        //Does text file exist
        //====================
        if (txtFile.Exists)
        {
            string line;
            string inputString = "";
            int input = 0;
            int num = 0;
            bool Fizz;
            bool Buzz;
            bool FizzBuzz;
            bool Prime;

            FizzBuzz fb = new FizzBuzz();

            StreamReader file = new StreamReader(path);         //Read File

            inputString = Console.ReadLine();

            //Read File line by line
            //=======================
            while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null){

                num = Convert.ToInt32(line);                    //Convert to Int  
                Console.WriteLine(num);

                Fizz = fb.IsFizz(num);                          //Is it a fizz

                Buzz = fb.IsBuzz(num);                          //Is it a Buzz

                FizzBuzz = fb.IsFizzBuzz(num);                  //Is it a FizzBuzz           

                Prime = fb.IsPrime(num);                        //Is the number a prime 

                Console.WriteLine("IsFizz " + fb.IsFizz(input));                           //Shows if IsFizz is true or false
                Console.WriteLine("IsBuzz " + fb.IsBuzz(input));                           //Shows if IsBuzz is true or false
                Console.WriteLine("IsFizzBuzz " + fb.IsFizzBuzz(input));                   //Shows if IsFizzBuzz is true or false
                Console.WriteLine("IsPrime " + fb.IsPrime(input));                         //Shows if IsPrime is true or false
                Console.WriteLine("Fizz Count total is " + fb.TotalFizz());                //Shows the total amount of Fizz counters 
                Console.WriteLine("Buzz Count total is " + fb.TotalBuzz());                //Shows the total amount of Buzz counters 
                Console.WriteLine("FizzBuzz Count total is " + fb.TotalFizzBuzz());        //Shows the total amount of FizzBuzz counters 
                Console.WriteLine("Prime Count total is " + fb.TotalPrime());              //Shows the total amount of Prime counters 

            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        else{
            Console.WriteLine("File Does not exist!");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
    //=================
    //Fizz Buzz Methods
    //=================

    public bool IsFizz(int input)
    {
        if (input % 9 == 0)
        {
            FizzCount++;                    //Add 1 to fizzCount
        }
        return true;
    }

    public bool IsBuzz(int input)
    {
        if (input % 13 == 0)
        {
            BuzzCount++;                    //Add 1 to buzzCount
        }
        return true;
    }

    public bool IsFizzBuzz(int input)
    {
        if ((input % 13 == 0) && (input % 9 == 0))
        {
            FizzBuzzCount++;                //Add 1 to fizzbuzzCount
        }
        return true;
    }

    public bool IsPrime(int input)          //It is only divisible by itself and one.
    {
        int i = 2;
        while (i * i <= input)
        {
            if ((input % i) == 0)
                return false;
            else i++;
        }
        PrimeCount++;                       //Add 1 to primeCount, prime count defined as int value
        return true;
    }
    public void BeginTesting()
    {
        FizzCount = 0;                      //Resets fizzCount
        BuzzCount = 0;                      //Resets buzzCount
        FizzBuzzCount = 0;                  //Resets fizzbuzzCount
        PrimeCount = 0;                     //Resets primeCount         
    }
    public int TotalFizz()
    {
        return FizzCount;
    }
    public int TotalBuzz()
    {
        return BuzzCount;
    }
    public int TotalFizzBuzz()
    {
        return FizzBuzzCount;
    }
    public int TotalPrime()
    {
        return PrimeCount;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You are always returning `true`in your `IsXxx()` methods. What's the point of the return value? And why does a method called `IsXxx()` count something at all?

Comment: `FizzBuzz fb = new FizzBuzz();` am I just blind or am I completely not seeing the FizzBuzz class?

Comment: You are going down the right path using the modulo operator (%).

What you want to do is create a string builder outside your file reading loop. Then, for each line of the file convert the line to an int and pass that int to a function that takes an int as input and returns a string. That function will have a simple if (input % 3 == 0 && input % 5 == 0) return "FizzBuzz" else if (input % 5 == 0) return "Buzz" else if (input % 3 == 0) return "Fizz" else return input.toString(). You will then append the output of that function to the string builder.

Comment: You're calling `IsFizz(...)` (and related methods) twice - once on `num` and once on `input`. Also, in regular FizzBuzz, a number is only one of Fizz, Buzz, or FizzBuzz - unsure whether that's the same in your homework example, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing two things which, when put together, cause your `FizzCount` (and related) values to increase every time through.

First, you're calling `IsFizz` twice - once on `input` and once on `num`. So you've got two chances to increase the `FizzCount` value each run through the loop.

Second, `input` is never set to be anything other than `0`.

This means that `if (input % 9 == 0)` returns `true` every time and increases the `FizzCount` value.

Answer (score 0):

Your FizzBuzz methods are always returning true, the return statement needs to be inside the if code block.

Change your method to the following:

```
public bool IsFizz(int input)
{
    if (input % 9 == 0)
    {
        FizzCount++;                    //Add 1 to fizzCount
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

Also be aware that your console messages are calling the methods again, which will iterate the counters by 2 instead of 1 in each loop of the while block. Change `Console.WriteLine("IsFizz " + fb.IsFizz(input));` to `Console.WriteLine("IsFizz " + Fizz);` as Fizz has already been resolved so you can just read its value.